# How do I convert all my enum options into an array for use in a collection for a dropdown menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have an enum on my class like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum status: [ :unconfirmed, :corroborated, :confirmed ]
end
```

I am using Simple Form, and I want to produce a dropdown menu in my form partial.

This is what I have now:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@post, html: {class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %> 

    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input_field :parent_id, as: :hidden %>

    <div class="field">
    <% if can? :manage, @post %>
            <%= f.input_field :status, label: "Status", collection: Post.statuses, selected: Post.statuses[:corroborated] %>    
    <% end %>       
    </div>

    <%= f.input :title, placeholder: "Enter Title" %>
    <%= f.input :photo %>
        <%= f.input :file %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
        <div class="report-submit">
            <%= f.button :submit %>
        </div>

<% end %>
```

When I create a new `Post` record, I get this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 20ms

ArgumentError - '2' is not a valid status:
```

When I do `Post.statuses` in my console, I get this:

```
 > Post.statuses
 => {"unconfirmed"=>0, "corroborated"=>1, "confirmed"=>2}
```

How can I do what I need with this `enum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `keys` of `enum` as `name` and `value` in collection. Meaning, you need to use `Post.statuses.keys` as collection:

```
<% statuses = Post.statuses %>
<%= f.input_field :status, label: "Status", collection: statuses.keys, selected: :corroborated %>
```

Comment: Ahh...Perfect. This works. One thing though, is there no way for me to use the symbols for the `:selected` attributes, rather than the string?

Comment: you may try symbol.. not sure about it.. give it a try

Comment: Good to know it works for you and we can use symbol while specifying default selected value... :)

Answer (score 1):

To have a select box I think this:

```
<%= f.input_field :status, label: "Status", collection: Post.statuses, selected: Post.statuses[:corroborated] %>
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(Post.statuses.collect { |s| [s[0].humanize, s[0]] }, selected: Post.statuses[:corroborated])%>
```

Also you might want to have the object's status as selected option? like so:

```
<%= f.select :status, options_for_select(Post.statuses.collect { |s| [s[0].humanize, s[0]] }, selected: post.status)%>
```

Comment: I am using simple_form, so maybe this may work for regular plain vanilla Rails forms...but it is too verbose for me right now. RAJ's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For example, assuming you have an enum like this one in your "Role" model (Role is just an example):

```
enum :work_type, in_person: "in_person", remote: "remote", hybrid: "hybrid"
```

Your answer could be this:

```
Role.work_types.collect { |key, value| [key.to_s.titleize, value] }
```

Depending on what Rails Form you use, your output should look like:

```
<select class="form__input" name="role[work_type]" id="role_work_type">
  <option selected="selected" value="in_person">In Person</option>
  <option value="remote">Remote</option>
  <option value="hybrid">Hybrid</option>
</select>
```